# django rest framework RetrieveUpdateAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I come from Vietnam.

I want to update User by Django Rest FrameWork. I can update User by 'pk'. But I can't update User by 'username'. I hope that everyone help me. Thank you so much.

## serializers.py

```
class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url_update = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='api:UserUpdateAPIView', lookup_field='username')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url_update', 'username', 'email', 'user_permissions', 'is_staff', 'groups', 'last_login')

class UserUpdateSerialier(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'}
    )
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk', 'username', 'password')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
        instance.set_password(validated_data.get('password', instance.password))
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

## views.py

```
class UserDetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer
    #queryset = User.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'username'
    def get_object(self):
        username = self.kwargs["username"]
        return get_object_or_404(User, username=username)

class UserUpdateAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)
    #queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserUpdateSerialier

    def get_object(self):
        username = self.kwargs["username"]
        return get_object_or_404(User, username=username)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^$', views.UserListAPIView.as_view(), name='UserListAPIView'),
url(r'^(?P<username>.*)/$', views.UserDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='UserDetailAPIView'),
url(r'^(?P<username>.*)/update/$', views.UserUpdateAPIView.as_view(), name='UserUpdateAPIView'),
```

> HTTP 404 Not Found
>
> Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Vary: Accept
>
> {
>       "detail": "Not found."
>   }

Answer (score 5):

Try editing your view like this,

```
class UserUpdateAPIView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)
    serializer_class = UserUpdateSerialier
    lookup_field = 'username'

    def get_object(self):
        username = self.kwargs["username"]
        return get_object_or_404(User, username=username)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I add lookup_field. But I can't update User. { "detail": "Not found." }

Comment: I got it. I edit urls.(?P<username>.*)=>(?P<username>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+). I have not add looked_field. But I edit urls. I done.

Comment: I want to show the data into the fields at the time of updation do you know how do we do that in nested serializing...... because otherwise I am getting null or blank fields, so if I edit one field it shows me an error, that these fields can't be blank or null.... please help.... Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `lookup_field = 'username'` to the `UserUpdateAPIView` just like you did with the `UserDetailAPIView`

Comment: I add lookup_field. But I can't update User. { "detail": "Not found." }

Comment: I got it. I edit urls.(?P<username>.*)=>(?P<username>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+). I have not add looked_field. But I edit urls. I done.

Comment: OP has done it but if someone else stumbles upon something like this, adding a `Content-Type: application/json` request header made it work for me.